# Why isn't my maven project appearing in Eclipse's 'Add and Remove' option for my application server?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, web.xml, application-server, deployment-descriptor

With the newest versions of the jboss wildfly being compatible to the Jakarte EE 10 specs we updated our JEE 8 projects. In this process we updated all our components, but afterwards the newest verion of eclipse had a bugged handling of our projects.

Most importantly the Deployments Descriptor was not handled correct and it was not possible to deploy our projects using the  add and remove  option of the application server.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEJsl.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TEqn.png)

After a while we found out, that the actual version of eclipse does not support the web.xml in the version 6.0 yet.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldQ4D.png)

Changing the web.xml to the version 5.0 made the projects running again.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa9Mn.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/td7N6.png)

Comment: The answer is fairly straightforward: Eclipse needs to be upgraded to a version supporting Jakarta EE 10 / Servlet 6.0. This is not a programming problem.

Comment: What is the question?